# Can't Boot With SSD As Cache

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, ssd, cache

I have an issue where I can't boot into Windows 7 using a Crucial M4 SSD as cache.  I have two Caviar Blue's in a RAID1, and the SSD is set as the cache.

The motherboard is an MSI Z68A-GD65 B3.

When I try to boot, it says to insert bootable media and restart.

I have already booted into windows, and it was when I set it as cache that I could boot no more.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have your Caviar Blue setup in RAID mode before or after you installed Windows?

Comment: I had it set up before.

Comment: what was the problem?  You can post it as an answer to your own question so the community can benefit from it.